# Couchbase Server Crashing - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchbase

I have just set up a Ubuntu 12.04 x64 droplet on digital ocean and I have freshly installed couchbase 2.5.0 x64.

I am in the admin panel, and everything looks fine until I click on "documents" in the databucket tab.

I get a connection lost message then end up at the login screen again.

This is what appears in my log after logging back in:

```
Port server moxi on node 'babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1' exited with status 0.      Restarting. 
Messages: 2014-03-25 20:24:53: (cproxy_config.c.315) env: MOXI_SASL_PLAIN_USR (13)
2014-03-25 20:24:53: (cproxy_config.c.324) env: MOXI_SASL_PLAIN_PWD (8)

WARNING: curl error: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining from:      http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

WARNING: curl error: couldn't connect to host from: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

ERROR: could not contact REST server(s): http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

WARNING: curl error: couldn't connect to host from: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

ERROR: could not contact REST server(s): http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

WARNING: curl error: couldn't connect to host from: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

ERROR: could not contact REST server(s): http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

WARNING: curl error: couldn't connect to host from: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

ERROR: could not contact REST server(s): http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

WARNING: curl error: couldn't connect to host from: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

ERROR: could not contact REST server(s): http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

WARNING: curl error: couldn't connect to host from: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

ERROR: could not contact REST server(s): http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

WARNING: curl error: couldn't connect to host from: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

EOL on stdin. Exiting
```

If anyone could shine a light on this I would be most grateful. I have search and search on Google but feel like I'm hitting brick walls

**UPDATE**

My Droplet was 512mb ram and I resized it to 1GB and now it works. I also added a swap file to the server.

I will leave this here incase someone else comes across this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a reference Couchbase themselves recommend minimum spec machines to have the following characteristics:

Minimum Spec if using Key/Value only:

Processor: Dual-core CPU running at 2GHz 
RAM: 4GB

Minimum Spec if using Key/Value AND Views or XDCR:

Processor: Six cores running at 3GHz
RAM: 16GB

Also bare in mind the following two things are very important:

> For smaller systems, such as those with less than 16GB you should allocate at least 40% of RAM to your operating system.

and

> At least twice the disk space to match your physical RAM for persistence of information

References -> http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.1/#resource-requirements

P.s. It is possible to run on much lower spec machines but I 100% wouldn't recommend it for production.